# How to calculate factorial of a factorial recursively?

Tags: recursion, data-structures, computer-science

I have encountered the following problem:
N is positive non-zero integer and I have to calculate the product of : `N*(N-1)^2*(N-2)^3*..*1^N`.

My solution so far is as follows:
`N*myFact(N-1)*fact(N-1)`

The thing is I'm not allowed to use any helping functions, such as `'fact()'`.

EDIT: Mathematically it can be represented as follows: N!*(N-1)! *(N-2)!*..*1!

Comment: Could provide an example of the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is called the [superfactorial](https://oeis.org/A000178). A recursive implementation is

```
long superFact(n) {
  if (n < 2) return 1;
  long last = superFact(n-1);
  long prev = superFact(n-2);
  return last * last / prev * n;
}
```

but this is very inefficient -- it takes about 3*F(n) recursive calls to find `superFact(n)`, where `F(n)` is the n-th Fibonacci number. (The work grows exponentially.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int myFact(int n) {
  return n == 1 ? 1 : myFact(n-1)*n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't solve the problem, it gives N!, what I need to calculate is, say N=5: 5*(4^2)*(3^3)*(2^4)*(1^5), which can be translated to 5!*4!*3!*2!*1!

Answer (score 0):

I assume this needs to be accomplished with 1 function i.e. you're not allowed to create a `fact` helper function yourself.

You can use the fact that `myFact(n-1) / myFact(n-2) == (n-1)!`

```
int myFact(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return 1
    } else {
        // (n - 1)!
        int previousFact = myFact(n - 1) / myFact(n - 2);
        return myFact(n - 1) * previousFact * n;
    }
}
```